# Non-relevant XBL control initialization inside repeat

Tags: orbeon

A XBL control which is bound to a non-relevant node is behaving differently when placed inside a repeat.

Why is xforms-enabled event fired on a non-relevant node inside repeat? init, xforms-enabled and xforms-disabled are called in sequence.

https://gist.github.com/1013671

An example is attached (relevant-error.xhtml). Same control outside repeat works as expected(relevant-without-repeat.xhtml)

Comment: just a quick note to say that I was able to reproduce this, and it looks like a bug. We will investigate and follow-up here.

Answer (score 1):

This is also happening with a regular `xforms:repeat`, not involving XBL. When you do an `xforms:insert`, the subtree of controls corresponding to the nodes you inserted is created right away. At that point, since the binds haven't be re-evaluated yet, the controls are all relevant, hence the `xforms-enabled`. Then you get an `xforms-disabled` when the binds are evaluated. Erik [took some notes](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=350207&aid=316003&group_id=168) about this, including possible ways in which this could be improved / fixed.

In the meantime, I would make sure that you don't do anything in your code on `xforms-enabled` that isn't undone on `xforms-disabled`. If that is the case, then the spurious `xforms-enabled` and `xforms-disabled` should not cause a problem, other than unnecessarily slow things down.